# Strange First Page Generated by \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Tags: input-encodings

I started learning LaTex ca 1 year ago at sharelatex.com. There it was said that the package `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` should always be included in your document preamble if unsure. However, I have now noticed that this package generates a strange first page in my latest document. The page has the following ununderstandable text:

> "orsta85Maclaurin-utvecklingequation.2.8 orstakonstant95Maclaurin-utvecklingequation.2.9orstaapp105Maclaurin-utvecklingequation.2.10 a116Maclaurin-utvecklingequation.2.11".

Then on page 2 comes the heading and the rest of the document looks completely normal.

If I remove `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` the strange first page disappears, but so does my Swedish characters (å,ä,ö), despite having `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` as well. I have tried removing both packages as well, but the result is the same.

Do you have any suggestion how this issue could be solved?

My preamble looks like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[swedish]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{wrapfig}

\graphicspath{ {Images/} }

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Thank you! :)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). Furthermore, it would help us help you if you post a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) (i.e. with `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`)

Comment: Delete all the auxiliary files and check if none of your labels contain any accented letters, they are forbidden. Does this change anything?

Comment: Not error message on my system (however, I had to remove `wrapfig` from the preamble, because it was not installed on my system).

Comment: Thank you for your advice! 
I didn't know that accented letters were forbidden in labels. Removing them solved the issue. Thank you very much! :)